# Orthogonality of two wave functions

Tags: orthogonality, quantum-mechanics

I have given two normalized wave functions $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\eta\rangle$ (including the eigenfunctions of the operator $A$) and a hermitian operator $A$ with non-degenerate eigenfunctions and eigenvalues. I have to determine whether the two wave functions are orthogonal or not without any major calculations, but how do I do that? Could I argue that because the eigenfunctions are orthogonal, the wave functions containing them are too? I know that the integral of the two functions need to be $0$ to be orthogonal.

Comment: This question needs clarification (and might be better on physics stack exchange) - what does "including the eigen functions of the operator" mean? It sounds to me like the trick will be to take advantage of the fact that eigen functions of a hermitian operator corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal

Comment: What I meant by "including the eigen functions of the operator" is for instance: $|\psi \rangle$ = $(5 + 3i)|\phi_1$ - $(2+3i)|\phi_2$ and   $|\eta \rangle$ = $(6 -2i)|\phi_3$ - $(16+4i)|\phi_4$ (where $\phi_n$ are the eigenfunctions of the operator (these are just made up functions and not the ones given in the task)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $|\eta\rangle = a|\phi_{1}\rangle + b|\phi_{2}\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle = c|\phi_{1}\rangle + d|\phi_{2}\rangle$ we work out the inner product:

$$\langle \eta | \psi \rangle = (a^{\star}\langle\phi_{1}| + b^{\star}\langle\phi_{2}|)(c|\phi_{1}\rangle + d|\phi_{2}\rangle)$$

You will use the fact that the eigenvalues of a self adjoint operator are orthogonal and can be chosen to be orthonormal: expand the inner product (using linearity) and apply $\langle \phi_{i} | \phi_{j} \rangle = \delta_{ij}$ so that cross terms will vanish and "non-crossed" terms will combine to cancel.

Does that help?

If your comment is correct and the states $|\psi\rangle $ and $|\eta\rangle$ are constructed from disjoint members of the set of eigenfunctions then orthogonality follows trivially.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Inserting an identity $\int dx|x\rangle\langle x|$ in the middle of $\langle\psi|\eta\rangle=0$ gives$$0=\int dx\langle\psi|x\rangle\langle x|\eta\rangle=\int dx\psi^\ast(x)\eta(x).$$This integral is the usual inner product on wavefunctions.

Comment: But why do I insert an identity and how does it exactly help me to show if the functions are orthogonal?

Comment: @ethopla You're trying to prove the vectors' orthogonality ($\langle\psi|\eta\rangle=0$) implies the functions' orthogonality ($\int dx\psi^\ast(x)\eta(x)=0$). You insert an identity because, well, it works.